# An alternative way to write document.write()

Tags: javascript, blogger

Is there an alternative way to write document.write() for this one?

I didn't know that it's bad and I've just started learning JavaScript, so I still don't know a lot of things about it.

Could you help me to fix this one?

```
if (thisUrl.indexOf("?q=") == -1 && thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1) {
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") == -1) {
        currentPage = "page";
        if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
            currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
        } else {
            currentPageNo = 1
        }
        document.write("<script src=\"" + home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata\"><\/script>")
    } else {
        currentPage = "label";
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("&max-results=") == -1) {
            perPage = 20
        }
        if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
            currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
        } else {
            currentPageNo = 1
        }
        document.write('<script src="' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary/-/' + postLabel + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata&max-results=1" ><\/script>')
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you only want to add a script to the page. You can do it using [DOM Manipulations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you can use `document.createElement('script')` to create a DOM Element, set its `src` property and then use `document.head.appendChild(yourObj)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method instead. For convenience you can wrap it in a function. E.g:

```
if (thisUrl.indexOf("?q=") == -1 && thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1) {
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") == -1) {
        currentPage = "page";
        if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
            currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
        } else {
            currentPageNo = 1
        }
        createScript(home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata")
    } else {
        currentPage = "label";
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("&max-results=") == -1) {
            perPage = 20
        }
        if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
            currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
        } else {
            currentPageNo = 1
        }
        createScript(home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary/-/' + postLabel + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata&max-results=1')
    }

}

function createScript(src){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

If you really do find yourself in a situation where you need to quickly add some HTML like with `document.write` you can use the [jQuery.append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method instead. jQuery is often not necessary these days and has it's own drawbacks but in this case it is still far better than using `document.write`